# Calling a function which has one of the parameters already assigned a value

Tags: python

According to Python docs it is illegal to define a function as `def test(a, b = 1, c):` - any subsequent parameter to a parameter which has a default value `(b = 1)` also needs to be defined with a default value. The correct way would be `def test(a, b = 1, c = 2):`
Can someone explain it?

**Edited:** I think that having *Polymorphism* in title was confusing. Title has been changed to reflect the content of the question

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This has naught to do with 'polymorphism' (and I am strong proponent of different kinds of polymorphism), but rather 'default values' or 'keyword arguments'. This restriction is in place because it avoids undecidable situations with parameter bindings.

Comment: @Zero Pireus: My question is different. It does not relate  to what you suggested.

Comment: @flamenco It does *not* have anything to do with polymorphism. If you think it does then please *provide a supporting resource*. (Because this is not covered in any form of polymorphism [defined here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29).)

Comment: Your question, as written, is too broad to be a good fit for Stack Overflow. I voted to put it on hold as a duplicate instead to help you out; you appear to be asking why positional arguments may not follow keyword arguments, and the accepted answer to the linked question answers that. If that's not what you're actually asking, you need to clarify your question (as it stands, "unclear what you're asking" would also be a valid reason to put it on hold).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define a default value for a parameter, it implicitly becomes *optional* in Python. This means that you don't need to call it with an explicit argument, the default argument is stored upon the time of the function's creation and is used whenever you don't supply an argument.

So in the case of `test(a, b=1, c=2)`, you could pass in one argument(a), or two arguments (a and b) or three arguments (a, b, c). The Python compiler/interpreter will figure out which argument belongs to which parameter based on which arguments you pass in, and in the order that you passed them in (unless you use explicit keys for the optional arguments, then you can switch the order).

But now think, if the function were defined as `test(a, b=1, c)`, how would the compiler/interpreter figure out what a call like `test(x, y)` does? `x` is obvious, it's an argument to `a`. But for `y`, is it an argument to `c` (which would be required, but then `y` is being passed in as the *second* parameter which makes no sense since we're skipping `b`), or an implicit argument to `b` (which doesn't make sense since then c is a required parameter with no argument)?

As you can see, this call makes no sense either way, so Python requires that all required parameters be bundled together as the first arguments to the call to avoid confusion.